# Gradle - Multiple Dex ConnectedInstrumentTest

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a jar in lib folder and added this lib as File dependency.

Generating build with `./gradlew build` is successful.

But `./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest` is showing Multiple dex error for that jar added in lib folder.

suggest me what is going wrong here.

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }



        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')

    }
}
```

***Module Dependency:***

[image]

***lib folder in project:***

[image]

Comment: Multiple dex files pointing to conscore lib class. I have found comscore lib is added twice in build folder. I didnt get any clue of from where it is added twice

Comment: You'll need to include information about all your build.gradle files and the rest of your directory structure. There's not enough information to diagnose it based on what's here so far.